# PHP - Get all XML files in directory from external URL

Tags: php, xml, glob

I'm trying to use glob() to get all of the XML files from an external URL, but I'm not getting any results back

```
foreach(glob("http://www.externalsite.com/files/*xml") as $filename) {
    $xml_file = file_get_contents($filename, FILE_TEXT);
    echo $filename;
 }
```

Is this possible? Or is there another method of doing this?

Comment: Does the URL allow directory listing? Meaning, when you go to it, does it show you all the files in the directory? I don't think glob can pull from a remote directory. I haven't tested it, but seems like it wouldn't work due to security reasons. If there is a directory listing, you may have to parse the page to extract all the links from it.

Comment: Glob wont work, http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php, `This function will not work on remote files as the file to be examined must be accessible via the server's filesystem.` Your best bet would probably be `file_get_contents` on `http://www.externalsite.com/files/` and then parse the URLs if the listing is public.

Comment: yes the URL allows directory listing. I will try flie_get_contents, thanks